# store columns of a formula with vba

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I am being asked to pull some old information out of an Excel file and put it into a new Access Database. The first thing I need to do is gather information from the columns that are in a formula for each department. So I have a formula that looks like this `=YP199+YT199+ZL199+ZT199` and I need to take column `YP199` get the info I need and so on. Once I can get the column from the formula the rest shouldn't be to hard.

Comment: Are you trying to store the contents of YP199 in a variable, or the sum of contents of YP1 - YP199, or something else?  It's not clear what you're asking for.

Comment: I am storing the column so I can pull information from the cells I need so i can create another table on a different sheet and export it. Basically someone created a sheet for rack orders and each column is a parts list that is charged to a different department. One depart might have 20 different columns associated with them.

Answer (score 0):

This code will give the the cell addresses of all the cell addresses which are direct precedents of the formula. Please note that I have not done any error handling. I am sure that you can take care of it?

I am assuming that Cell A1 of Sheet1 has the formula `=YP199+YT199+ZL199+ZT199`

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range, acell As Range

    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        Set rng = .Range("A1")
        For Each acell In rng.DirectPrecedents
            Debug.Print acell.Address
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

The above code when run will give you this.

```
$YP$199
$YT$199
$ZL$199
$ZT$199
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That definitely looks better than what I came up with.